# How display only the urls in my browsable Web API, which the user has permission?

Tags: django, routes, django-rest-framework, django-urls, django-1.8

I am using **Python 3.4**, **Django 1.8.4** and **DjangoRestFramework 3.2.2**

By Default, the django rest framework, displays all available urls, and if the person tries to access any url that does not have permission, it displays an error that is not allowed

```
"detail": "You do not have permission to perform this action."
```

From what I saw in [class DefaultRouter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter), it is only loaded once, when I go up the server,

I noticed that on line **283** of rest_framework/routers.py, there is a hardcoded field.

```
class APIRoot (views.APIView):
            _ignore_model_permissions = True
```

I've changed to False and nothing happened **all urls are loaded.**

I tried to understand how the [Custom Router](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#custom-routers) work, but would not solve my problem.

Anyone know if there is any way that I can display only the urls in my browsable Web API, which the user has permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I overwrite the DefaultRouter class of **django-rest-framework**.
Now, if the user doesn't has the permission to list the object, the url doesn't will appear.

```
class UrlRouter(DefaultRouter):

    def get_api_root_view(self):
        """
        Return a view to use as the API root.
        """
        api_root_dict = OrderedDict()
        list_name = self.routes[0].name
        for prefix, viewset, basename in self.registry:
            api_root_dict[prefix] = list_name.format(basename=basename)

        class APIRoot(views.APIView):
            _ignore_model_permissions = True

            def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
                ret = OrderedDict()
                namespace = request.resolver_match.namespace
                for key, url_name in api_root_dict.items():
                    if namespace:
                        if request.user.has_perm(key.split('-')[0]+'_list'):
                            url_name = namespace + ':' + url_name
                    try:
                        from django.conf.urls import url
                        ret[key] = reverse(
                            url_name,
                            args=args,
                            kwargs=kwargs,
                            request=request,
                            format=kwargs.get('format', None)
                        )
                    except NoReverseMatch:
                        # Don't bail out if eg. no list routes exist, only detail routes.
                        continue
                return Response(ret)
        return APIRoot.as_view()
```